# Sitecore solr and muiltilist with search

Tags: search, solr, sitecore

I've set up a new instance of Sitecore, added some items and created a multilist with search, all works fine until I move to solr.

After enabled debug on search I've got that Sitecore is sending to solr the following query

`((-_group:(d4882314400a467fad6f84bbb58acd03) -_group:(15fbfc2f4af34e0dbdf0a094332127bb)) AND _templatename:(Ship))`

The problem is that query doesn't return anything in solr the correct query should be

`(-_group:(d4882314400a467fad6f84bbb58acd03) -_group:(15fbfc2f4af34e0dbdf0a094332127bb) AND _templatename:(Ship))`

But I'm finding hard to accept that Sitecore just doesn't work with solr and multilist with search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug and worth raising with Sitecore Support.

There are a number of known issues with Multilist with search.

Take a look at this knowledge base article to see if the solution works for you:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/372032

Answer (score 0):

You needs to create a custom index for multi-list.

```
public class SearchCategoryComputedField : IComputedIndexField
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }

        public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
        {
            string multilistValues="";
            //Write logic here to get your selected values of multi list
            return multilistValues;
        }
```

Also add path config for custom index, then rebuilt your index.